# iOS 8.0 Beta Unknown UIKit Log

Tags: ios8, xcode6

Xcode Beta Version 6.0 (6A267n), iOS 8.0 Beta 5 (12A4345d)

I'm getting an unknown log related to uikit library that I've never seen before.

> 17545849:_UIScreenEdgePanRecognizerEdgeSettings.edgeRegionSize=13.000000

It looks like `UIKit.h` associated libraries, but I can't find `UIScreenEdgePanRecognizerEdgeSetting`s.

What is it?

Comment: It's most likely issue related to Apple's code not yours. File the bug to them

Comment: getting this log message in xcode 6 beta 6 also

Comment: This seems to be back in beta 6.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a bug, and it's a known one, see http://prod.lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2014/Aug/msg00030.html

> Yea, sorry about that. Its already been removed, no further bugs necessary.

Comment: I'm still seeing it in b7. I guess it was removed but not pushed to their master branch?

Comment: I guess it might not present in Xcode 6 GM seed version. Or wait for a stable Xcode 6.

Comment: Still in Version 6.1 (6A1027) (weird name - why not just 6.0)